# Get fields of log in Grok Debugger Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I have a log for one application in my apache server.

In Kibana I have this information in message field:

```
INFO [20 jul 2018 09:25:21] PoolJDBC - [Pool Properties] NumConnections: 50 | NumBusyConnections: 2 | NumIdleConnections: 48
```

I need to get this Fields:

```
Date / Time: 20 jul 2018 09:25:21
NumConnections: 50
NumBusyConnections: 2
NunIdleConnections: 48
```

How can I get this information in Grok Debugger?

Comment: To debug grok filter, here's useful ressources: a [tester](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result) and the [default grok patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern:

```
^%{LOGLEVEL} \[%{DATA:date}\].*NumConnections: %{INT:NumConnections} \| NumBusyConnections: %{INT:NumBusyConnections} \| NumIdleConnections: %{INT:NumIdleConnections}
```

Gave me this results:

```
date    20 jul 2018 09:25:21
NumConnections  50
NumBusyConnections  2
NumIdleConnections  48
```

I used `^%{LOGLEVEL}` at the start in order to anchor the start of the regex and speed it up.

Also note that for the number of connections part, you can use the [kv](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) filter with `|` as field split and `:` as value split: it should give you the same results as the grok pattern above but would allow your logstash configuration to keep working if that part of your log format changes.

Comment: Hi baudsp, Thank you for your support.